# How to find when my vm was resized in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, resize, virtual-machine, instance, activitylog

I created a VM in GCP with a 2 core 8GB Ram config, later i noticed it was changed to 4 core and 16 GB Ram. I need to find out who did this and when from my team.

I tried going through the activity dashboard but its quiet difficult to understand from that. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Changes to a Compute Engine configuration will be logged in the Admin Activity audit logs. The IAM identity that changed the instance will be logged.

The following CLI command will read the log. Replace PROJECT_ID with your Project ID.

```
gcloud logging read "logName : projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com" --project=PROJECT_ID
```

[Understanding audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/understanding-audit-logs)

[Compute Engine audit logging information](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/audit-logging)

[gcloud logging read](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read)